# How do I install an older version of a django package?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install `django-excel`, but it seems like it has been upgraded to function with Django 1.9+

I'm using Django 1.8 and would like to make the package work again. I tried this, but I want to go back to a previous version(Django 1.7+):

```
pip install django-excel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install a prior version like so:

```
pip install django-excel==0.1
```

Similar to how it appears if you run the `pip freeze` command.

Comment: Ok thank! I'll uninstall first with `pip uninstall django-excel`

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall django

pip install django==<version>
```

Comment: If you tried this, you'd get an error from pip. `= is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?`.

Comment: yeah i meant ==. Thanks. modified